# Is it possible to trigger the onclick event of activity in background service?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

For example, I started an activity, there is a button in the activity

And then I start the background service, this service will check whether the target activity is on foreground, then trigger the click event of that button.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: theoretically if you have the context and button instance then yes. You using yourBtn.performClick();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you trigger a click event of an activity rather than notifying the activity about its results? Try to use local broadcasts which are sent from the service to the activity. The activity registers for that broadcast and in its `onReceive` of the `BroadcastReceiver` you'll trigger your `onClick` method or any other method of your choice. The Receiver is registered in `onResume` and unregistered in `onPause` to guarantee that the activity is actually visible.

I would not recommend to use a direct dependency on your activity as this might cause `IllegalStateExceptions` if in any circumstance your activity is not started or visible at all.

Answer (score 2):

I can strongly recommend you to use eventbus concept like "otto by square" in this case.
you will subscribe to event from the activity this will keep to modularity and will let you do this function